# How to I import data from csv to gcp datastore

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I have been trying to import a sample nosql db to gcp datastore. when stored in gcs datastore is asking for data in specific extension i.e
.overall_export_metadata.

Comment: If the file you're trying to import is a sample, it makes sense that you don't have an `.overall_export_metadata` file. Those metadata files are only created by Datastore export processes, and it sounds like your sample file didn't come with an attached metadata file. Just in case, though, you could look for the phrase "Locating your `overall_export_metadata` file" in this page - https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/export-import-entities#importing_all_entities - and that should give you a shot at finding where there might possibly be one of those files in your project.

Comment: This comment presents a very good insight of the issue, could you please confirm if this was useful to your issue?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there are any existing tools that can just import a CSV into datastore. You could write a Google Dataflow job to do this.

https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/

https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/quickstarts

It does look like they provide a template-based job that takes in a JSON file and writes it to datastore

https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-batch#gcstexttodatastore

JSON format:

https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/data/rest/v1/Entity