# How to migrate the data from AWS DynamoDB to Google Cloud Datastore?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to migrate data from AWS dynamodb to google cloud datastore, but there is no prior information available on this problem. I could find few links for migrating from datastore to dynamodb or migrating from dynamodb to cloud spanner.

I've tried to explore import/export option through csv file, but only import/export to firestore is available on google documentation.

Comment: Looks like datastore import/export uses [leveldb log format](https://github.com/google/leveldb/blob/main/doc/log_format.md). Also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66893460/how-to-i-import-data-from-csv-to-gcp-datastore).

Answer (score 0):

For a bulk import, you are probably best to start with the Dataflow template for Firestore in Datastore mode at https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-batch#cloud-storage-text-to-firestore .  You can provide a transform function to transform your data, or update the template to match your needs.